# Summary (mySQL) of WooCommerce Purchases Per Club Membership

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating two "user admin" pages for our clubs, so they can see what each of their members are purchasing in WooCommerce. I've got most of the mySQL query complete, just need to finish some minor points (bit over my head).

```
SELECT
    wp_users.ID,
    wp_users.display_name AS 'Name',
    wp_ihc_user_levels.level_id AS 'Roles',

    -- Check if User if full member or club visitor
    (CASE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'club_member'
        WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE 'Visitor' THEN 'Sponsored Visitor'
        WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE 'Member' THEN 'Financial Member'
    END) AS 'Membership',

    -- Check if Member has purchased any items, by "category"
    (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'Yes', 'No') FROM wp_terms
            WHERE wp_users.ID AND name = 'Camping') AS 'Camping',
    (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'Yes', 'No') FROM wp_terms
            WHERE wp_users.ID AND name = 'Merchandise') AS 'Merchandise',
    (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'Yes', 'No') FROM wp_terms
            WHERE wp_users.ID AND name = 'Catering') AS 'Catering',
    (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'Yes', 'No') FROM wp_terms
            WHERE wp_users.ID AND name = 'Tickets') AS 'Tickets',

    -- Check if Member has booked any trips
    (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'Yes', 'No') FROM wp_em_bookings WHERE person_id = wp_users.ID) AS 'Trips'
FROM
    wp_users
    JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
    JOIN wp_ihc_user_levels ON wp_users.ID = wp_ihc_user_levels.user_id
WHERE
    wp_usermeta.meta_value = (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'affiliated_club' THEN meta_value END) FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = '17')
```

So the SQL query would run as the user_id who called the query, it would then find all other club members in "affiliate_club", and run the SELECT queries from the top.

Issues are:

1. A user can have multiple roles in "wp_ihc_user_levels.level_id", however the query is returning 2 lines for "4" and "5", instead of CONCAT i.e.   "4,5" in same row.
2. CASE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'club_member' is returning "Visitor" for all entries, where there are some full members
3. I'm uncertain which WooCommerce tables I need to query, to link Categories to each wp_users.ID purchases for count.

The second query, I need to use "wp_users.ID" returned from query one, to expand each of the WooCommerce purchases in more detail, sorted by category.

I can probably do most of the second query, if I understand the WooCommerce query one further.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1:**

OK, So I was able to get Point 1 sorted out:

Changed:

```
wp_ihc_user_levels.level_id AS 'Roles',
```

To:

```
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(level_id SEPARATOR ',')
    FROM wp_ihc_user_levels
    WHERE user_id = wp_users.ID) AS 'Roles',
```

Now "Roles" shows values "2,3,5" etc.. instead of single values

**UPDATE 2:**

OK, So I've now got Point 2 sorted out:

Changed:

```
(CASE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'club_member'
    WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE 'Visitor' THEN 'Sponsored Visitor'
    WHEN wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE 'Member' THEN 'Financial Member'
END) AS 'Membership',
```

To:

```
(SELECT wp_usermeta.meta_value
    FROM wp_usermeta
    WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'club_member' AND wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID) AS 'Membership',
```

**UPDATE 3: SQL Query Completed**

Ok, so this was either an extremely complex SQL query, or I've structured it all wrong, but my working solution is below.

**NOTE:** The %CURRENT_USER_ID% placeholder is used to call the current user ID, where they exist in the same club as other members.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    wpdc_users.ID,
    wpdc_users.display_name AS 'Name',

    (SELECT wpdc_usermeta.meta_value
        FROM wpdc_usermeta
        WHERE wpdc_usermeta.meta_key = 'club_member' AND wpdc_usermeta.user_id = wpdc_users.ID) AS 'Membership',

    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(level_id SEPARATOR ',')
        FROM wpdc_ihc_user_levels
        WHERE user_id = wpdc_users.ID) AS 'Roles',

    (SELECT
        IF(SUM(wpdc_terms.name = 'Camping')     >0, 'Yes', 'No')

    FROM
        wpdc_postmeta
        JOIN wpdc_woocommerce_order_items ON wpdc_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wpdc_postmeta.post_id
        JOIN wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wpdc_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
        JOIN wpdc_term_relationships ON wpdc_term_relationships.object_id = wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        JOIN wpdc_terms ON wpdc_terms.term_id = wpdc_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id

    WHERE
        wpdc_postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND wpdc_term_relationships.object_id = wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        AND wpdc_terms.term_id = wpdc_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
        AND wpdc_terms.term_id > 23
        AND wpdc_postmeta.meta_value =  wpdc_users.ID) AS 'Camping',

    (SELECT
        IF(SUM(wpdc_terms.name = 'Catering')    >0, 'Yes', 'No')

    FROM
        wpdc_postmeta
        JOIN wpdc_woocommerce_order_items ON wpdc_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wpdc_postmeta.post_id
        JOIN wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wpdc_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
        JOIN wpdc_term_relationships ON wpdc_term_relationships.object_id = wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        JOIN wpdc_terms ON wpdc_terms.term_id = wpdc_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id

    WHERE
        wpdc_postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND wpdc_term_relationships.object_id = wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        AND wpdc_terms.term_id = wpdc_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
        AND wpdc_terms.term_id > 23
        AND wpdc_postmeta.meta_value =  wpdc_users.ID) AS 'Catering',

    (SELECT
        IF(SUM(wpdc_terms.name = 'Merchandise') >0, 'Yes', 'No')

    FROM
        wpdc_postmeta
        JOIN wpdc_woocommerce_order_items ON wpdc_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wpdc_postmeta.post_id
        JOIN wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wpdc_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
        JOIN wpdc_term_relationships ON wpdc_term_relationships.object_id = wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        JOIN wpdc_terms ON wpdc_terms.term_id = wpdc_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id

    WHERE
        wpdc_postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND wpdc_term_relationships.object_id = wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        AND wpdc_terms.term_id = wpdc_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
        AND wpdc_terms.term_id > 23
        AND wpdc_postmeta.meta_value =  wpdc_users.ID) AS 'Merchandise',

    (SELECT
        IF(SUM(wpdc_terms.name = 'Tickets')     >0, 'Yes', 'No')

    FROM
        wpdc_postmeta
        JOIN wpdc_woocommerce_order_items ON wpdc_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wpdc_postmeta.post_id
        JOIN wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wpdc_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
        JOIN wpdc_term_relationships ON wpdc_term_relationships.object_id = wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        JOIN wpdc_terms ON wpdc_terms.term_id = wpdc_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id

    WHERE
        wpdc_postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND wpdc_term_relationships.object_id = wpdc_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        AND wpdc_terms.term_id = wpdc_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
        AND wpdc_terms.term_id > 23
        AND wpdc_postmeta.meta_value =  wpdc_users.ID) AS 'Tickets',

    (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'Yes', 'No') FROM wpdc_em_bookings WHERE person_id = wpdc_users.ID) AS 'Trips / Events'
FROM
    wpdc_users
    JOIN wpdc_usermeta ON wpdc_usermeta.user_id = wpdc_users.ID
    JOIN wpdc_ihc_user_levels ON wpdc_users.ID = wpdc_ihc_user_levels.user_id

WHERE
    wpdc_usermeta.meta_value = (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'affiliated_club' THEN meta_value END) FROM wpdc_usermeta WHERE user_id = %CURRENT_USER_ID%)
```

I'm going to mark this resolved, but would appreciate if anyone is able to advise if this can be compacted / minimised to run more efficiently to check each Category Purchase.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 3: SQL Query Completed**

Ok, so this was either an extremely complex SQL query, or I've structured it all wrong, but my working solution is below.

**NOTE:** The %CURRENT_USER_ID% placeholder is used to call the current user ID, where they exist in the same club as other members.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    wp_users.ID,
    wp_users.display_name AS 'Name',

    (SELECT wp_usermeta.meta_value
        FROM wp_usermeta
        WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'club_member' AND wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID) AS 'Membership',

    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(level_id SEPARATOR ',')
        FROM wp_ihc_user_levels
        WHERE user_id = wp_users.ID) AS 'Roles',

    (SELECT
        IF(SUM(wp_terms.name = 'Camping')     >0, 'Yes', 'No')

    FROM
        wp_postmeta
        JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wp_postmeta.post_id
        JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
        JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id

    WHERE
        wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        AND wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
        AND wp_terms.term_id > 23
        AND wp_postmeta.meta_value =  wp_users.ID) AS 'Camping',

    (SELECT
        IF(SUM(wp_terms.name = 'Catering')    >0, 'Yes', 'No')

    FROM
        wp_postmeta
        JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wp_postmeta.post_id
        JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
        JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id

    WHERE
        wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        AND wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
        AND wp_terms.term_id > 23
        AND wp_postmeta.meta_value =  wp_users.ID) AS 'Catering',

    (SELECT
        IF(SUM(wp_terms.name = 'Merchandise') >0, 'Yes', 'No')

    FROM
        wp_postmeta
        JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wp_postmeta.post_id
        JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
        JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id

    WHERE
        wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        AND wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
        AND wp_terms.term_id > 23
        AND wp_postmeta.meta_value =  wp_users.ID) AS 'Merchandise',

    (SELECT
        IF(SUM(wp_terms.name = 'Tickets')     >0, 'Yes', 'No')

    FROM
        wp_postmeta
        JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_items ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_id = wp_postmeta.post_id
        JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wp_woocommerce_order_items.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id
        JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id

    WHERE
        wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_customer_user'
        AND wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value
        AND wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
        AND wp_terms.term_id > 23
        AND wp_postmeta.meta_value =  wp_users.ID) AS 'Tickets',

    (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'Yes', 'No') FROM wp_em_bookings WHERE person_id = wp_users.ID) AS 'Trips / Events'
FROM
    wp_users
    JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_users.ID
    JOIN wp_ihc_user_levels ON wp_users.ID = wp_ihc_user_levels.user_id

WHERE
    wp_usermeta.meta_value = (SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'affiliated_club' THEN meta_value END) FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id = %CURRENT_USER_ID%)
```

I'm going to mark this resolved, but would appreciate if anyone is able to advise if this can be compacted / minimised to run more efficiently to check each Category Purchase.

Thanks in advance.